# Force an idle chat status in Facebook while still working in it and without going offline

Tags: facebook, status

One of my friends had asked me about how to keep chatting or working on Facebook and show **idle** status on Facebook, and I didn't find any way to force Facebook's chat to go **idle**.

I know that in order to have your status *Idle* you must not use Facebook for at least 10 minutes, if I am not wrong. But, I think there should be some way to change the status for chat, right?

How do I to do that?

**Note**
Don't propose to go offline for a chat. He knows it already, but he doesn't want to be offline on a chat.

Comment: This and a "busy" status would be useful.

Comment: lol, I like the title "How to keep *working* on facebook"... Does anyone actually *work* on Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short it is not efficient/possible for the Facebook team to deal with it.

The way I see it, idle is used to show that the user's attention is not in browsing Facebook. To elaborate, a user can be playing an intensive game (Bejeweled/Farmville) and end up in idle, but as soon as focus moves away from the game, online status resumes.

The best way *is* to go offline but for specific people using friend lists.

And here is an engineer from 2008 explaining why this is difficult

> The most resource-intensive operation
>   performed in a chat system is not
>   sending messages. It is rather keeping
>   each online user aware of the
>   online-idle-offline states of their
>   friends, so that conversations can
>   begin.
>
> The naive implementation of sending a
>   notification to all friends whenever a
>   user comes online or goes offline has
>   a worst case cost of O(average
>   friendlist size * peak users * churn
>   rate) messages/second, where churn
>   rate is the frequency with which users
>   come online and go offline, in
>   events/second. This is wildly
>   inefficient to the point of being
>   untenable, given that the average
>   number of friends per user is measured
>   in the hundreds, and the number of
>   concurrent users during peak site
>   usage is on the order of several
>   millions.
>
> Surfacing connected users' idleness
>   greatly enhances the chat user
>   experience but further compounds the
>   problem of keeping presence
>   information up-to-date. Each Facebook
>   Chat user now needs to be notified
>   whenever one of his/her friends  (a)
>   takes an action such as sending a chat
>   message or loads a Facebook page (if
>   tracking idleness via a last-active
>   timestamp) or  (b) transitions between
>   idleness states (if representing
>   idleness as a state machine with
>   states like "idle-for-1-minute",
>   "idle-for-2-minutes",
>   "idle-for-5-minutes",
>   "idle-for-10-minutes", etc.).  Note
>   that approach (a) changes the sending
>   a chat message / loading a Facebook
>   page from a one-to-one communication
>   into a multicast to all online
>   friends, while approach (b) ensures
>   that users who are neither chatting
>   nor browsing Facebook are nonetheless
>   generating server load.

[Source - [Facebook Engineering Notes - Facebook Chat](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919) ]

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it, but it might be worth investigating [a chat client](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) and linking it to Facebook.  From [the FAQs](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php#!/help/?topic=chatclient&__a=5&ajaxpipe=1), it looks like it might be possible to change status for certain friend lists. It may not work, but it looks like a good starting point.